# Одновременное проигрывание данных из разных источников

Tags: android, аудио, java

Я получаю из сети байты звука и проигрываю их через AudioTrack. Проблема в том, что между приемами байтов с разных источников слышны заикания (связь один ко одному работает на ура). Мне небходимо, чтобы данные, принятые из разных источников, проигрывались одновременно или чтобы создавалась видимость, что данные проигрываются одновременно. SoundPool делает подобное, но вроде требует предварительной загрузки аудиофрагмента. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда не использовал AudioTrack, но чисто логически - как раз во время переключения источников и происходит "разрыв". А звук - это не видео, слух намного более чувствителен к разрывам, чем зрение, и времени, за которое происходит смена источника достаточно, чтобы заметить это.  
Может, нужно импользовать по одному экземпляру AudioTrack на каждый источник, чтобы они воспроизводились независимо?